# Efficient method to split a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)
>   [Javascript: Splitting a string by comma but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617400/javascript-splitting-a-string-by-comma-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

I have a comma separated string like this:

```
car,jeep,,"ute,van",suv,truck
```

I need to split it and add it to array as following entries:

```
car
jeep

ute,van
suv 
truck
```

I am currently first splitting the string by " and then replace , with some other character in the parts that have , only in the middle but not at the either ends.

Also I check if the length of split array is greater than 1 because in case I get strings that don't have " at all, I want to skip the replacing , part.

Then finally I join the array using "" to get the end result.

Can someone suggest any better way and efficient way to do this possibly using regex?

Comment: You should use a [CSV parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data).

Comment: @ChaitanyaM: Uh, that *is*  pure JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @TimPietzcker for pointing me to CSV Parser. The algorithm there looks like an overkill and hard to understand. I believe my algorithm  is simple and easy to understand. So unless proven otherwise, I will stick to mine.

Comment: No problem to prove otherwise. CSV *is* a nontrivial format. Try this string: `',wood,"2"" by 4""","oak\ncomposite",'`. Your approach fails on escaped quotes and on empty field at the start and end of the string.

Comment: I can never have empty string at the start. I skip the parts that have , at the either or both ends. So having empty string at the end doesn't harm I believe. Also I missed one more step in my algo. I finally split the string by comma after replacing interim commas with say ;

Comment: Hey, it's your foot. You choose the gun :)